# Is there a DNF command that can list not-installed dependencies of a package?

Tags: linux, rpm, dnf

Reading the documentation for DNF, it is unclear to me how one even lists the required dependencies of a package (NOTE: *NOT* my question, my question is the title).

So what I'm wondering is, how would one go about listing the packages that needs installing to install package `foo`?

Meaning, I want to be able to query the package manager and be provided the same information that is displayed when user does `dnf install foo`, where it lists the packages it will install alongside `foo` - but I want to be able to do it without actually running the install command (because the context constrains me from doing so, I just need this metadata).

Would greatly appreciate any input to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "`rpm`" command like this "`rpm -V package_name`"

Example:

```bash
> LANG=C rpm -V qelectrotech-0.90-2.fc38.x86_64
Unsatisfied dependencies for qelectrotech-0:0.90-2.fc38.x86_64:
    qelectrotech-symbols = 0:0.90-2.fc38 is needed by (installed) qelectrotech-0:0.90-2.fc38.x86_64
```

Or for all installed packages:

```bash
> LANG=C rpm -Va | grep 'is needed by'
    qelectrotech-symbols = 0:0.90-2.fc38 is needed by (installed) qelectrotech-0:0.90-2.fc38.x86_64
```

or better with `-V` sub-options:

```bash
LANG=C rpm -Va --nofiles --noscripts --nosignature --nolinkto --nofiledigest --nosize --nouser --nogroup --nomtime --nomode --nordev  --nocaps
```